# SerialPort.GetPortNames() comparison for serial ports in C#

Tags: c#

I am testing a real-time port view for serial port.

The Form1 and debug state with always false is shown below.

When Form1 is created, the COM port list is stored in recordedPorts and timer1_Tick event is generated every 100ms, the current COM port list is read and stored in presentPorts and compared with recordedPorts. If you look at the debug state picture, you can see that the result value string[] each of GetPortNames() method is the same.

[image]

I want to display COM ports in comboBox1 in real time.

However, it could not be displayed in the comboBox1.

There was a problem in string operation, so timer1_Tick event could not be operated normally.

The first question is to know why string real-time comparison is always false,

and the second is whether there is any other way to display the serial port in real time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace TestSerial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] recordedPorts, presentPorts;

        string str;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            recordedPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string PortName in recordedPorts)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(PortName);
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                textBox1.Text += "disconnected." + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text += "already disconnected." + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
                //serialPort1.Open();
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Open();  //serial port open!!!
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }

                serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                textBox1.Text += "connected." + Environment.NewLine;

                serialPort1.WriteLine("abcd\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text += "already connected." + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            str = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

            if(str.Length > 8)
            {
                textBox1.SelectedText += str + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            presentPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            if (presentPorts.Count() == 0)
            {
                //if(comboBox1.Items.Count != 0) comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                recordedPorts = presentPorts;
                return;
            }

            if (recordedPorts != presentPorts)
            {
                comboBox1.DataSource = presentPorts;
                recordedPorts = presentPorts;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The debug state that is always false is as follows.

Comment: `recordedPorts != presentPorts` compares the two array references,not the content of the two arrays. You could use `recordedPorts.SequenceEquals(presentPorts)` instead (assuming both arrays are in the same order).

Comment: Wow!!!. Thanks a lot. I resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Klaus Gütter.
I resolved this question by comparing the content of the arrays instead of the array references.

Change it to the code below and it works normally.

```cs
if (!recordedPorts.SequenceEqual(presentPorts))
//if (recordedPorts != presentPorts)
{
    comboBox_port.DataSource = presentPorts;
    recordedPorts = presentPorts;
}
```